# MPI : getting number of nodes (not processes) in a communicator

Tags: c, mpi, communicator

I'm working with MPI programs on an SMP supercomputer. I would like to identify which processes are sharing the same node, for example by setting an integer key that is equal in all processes on the same node, and different from a node to another. The goal would be then to use this key to split a communicator and have sub-communicators gathering only the processes in the same node.

So the function would look like

```
int identify_node(MPI_Comm* comm); // returns a key characterizing a node
```

Assuming a simple distribution of processes like 0,1,2,3 on node_1, 4,5,6,7 on node_2, etc. it is a matter of a simple formula, but I would like to achieve the same result with no assumption on the distribution.

I have an idea how to do that using MPI_Get_processor_name : by computing a hash of the name and assume no two names will get the same hash (I don't like this because if one day I have two names with the same hash, it will be difficult to track the problem), or use some kind of agreement algorithm across processes (which one? I don't know yet).

How would you do that (efficiently if possible)?

Matthieu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The modern MPI 3 answer to this is to call `MPI_Comm_split_type`

---

*Old answer for posterity*

You're right that an assumption on the distribution would be unwise, since rank reordering is actually an up-and-coming technique for improving performance at the cost of that regularity.

A good hashing algorithm on the return value of `MPI_Get_processor_name` should be pretty safe, but if you want to double-check, you could always gather up the actual names within each group using `MPI_Gatherv` and compare them directly.

It seems [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041935/group-mpi-tasks-by-host) addresses the same concerns.

Comment: Thank you, the question you mentioned is indeed pretty close. I think I will do what you advise: get a hash of processor name, then perform a second check with MPI_Gatherv.